# What are the default nmap options?

Tags: networking, port, tcp, nmap

Which options are used by default, when the user fires

```
# nmap target
```

without any explicit option?

I am going to write the defaults of the three options I consider the most important. It would be nice to have all the default options, probably with some short commentary on when it is appropriate to change them.

The most important distinction I can think of is, that under root a TCP **SYN** scan (-sS) is used by default, while under regular user it uses TCP **Connect()** scan (-sT), as it has not privileges to work with raw packets.

Second think are the **target (TCP) ports**. The [docs](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-specification.html) says, that "Normally Nmap scans the most common 1,000 ports for each scanned protocol". I presume these are some selected ports lower than 1024, probably known services.

The last thing of interest are **scan timings**, for IDS evasion.

```
-T paranoid|sneaky|polite|normal|aggressive|insane (Set a timing template)
```

The default is of course

```
-T3
```

or

```
-T normal
```

Comment: the "top 1000 ports" are defined per the nmap-services file. https://nmap.org/book/nmap-services.html They were originally based on the well known ports (<1024), but the list has been expanded and lesser used ports under 1024 have gotten knocked off the list.

Answer (score 1):

per the [man](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/nmap1.html), the default scan with no other options specified varies based on user privledge.

for Privledged users, the default option is the `-sS` scan:

> TCP SYN scan: This technique is often referred to as "half-open"
>                 scanning, because you don’t open a full TCP connection. You send
>                 a SYN packet, as if you are going to open a real connection  and
>                 you wait for a response. A SYN|ACK indicates the port is listen-
>                 ing. A RST is indicative of a non-listener.   If  a  SYN|ACK  is
>                 received,  a RST is immediately sent to tear down the connection
>                 (actually our OS kernel does this for us). The primary advantage
>                 to  this  scanning  technique  is  that fewer sites will log it.
>                 Unfortunately you need root privileges to build these custom SYN
>                 packets.  This is the default scan type for privileged users.

and for unpriledged users, the default option is the `-sT` scan:

> TCP connect() scan: This is the most basic form of TCP scanning.
>                 The connect() system call provided by your operating  system  is
>                 used  to  open  a  connection  to  every interesting port on the
>                 machine. If the port is listening, connect() will succeed,  oth-
>                 erwise  the  port  isn’t reachable. One strong advantage to this
>                 technique is that you don’t need  any  special  privileges.  Any
>                 user on most UNIX boxes is free to use this call.
>
> This  sort of scan is easily detectable as target host logs will
>                 show a bunch of connection and error messages for  the  services
>                 which  accept() the connection just to have it immediately shut-
>                 down.  This is the default scan type for unprivileged users.

so thats two of your profiles right there.

Comment: Yes, but that's just the scan type. What about other options, for example the timing. The default is `-T3`, but there are `-T1,-T2,-T4,-T5` as well and I am sure the situation is similar with other options.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that by default nmap target  does not find an open port of 2080.

If I specified this by -p 2080 it found it open. sT and sS did not find this port open.

nmap -p- target did find it.

Comment: Because by default nmap tries only the top 1000 TCP/UDP ports. By specifying `-p 2080` you overwrite that option and scan specifically for 2080. By specifying `-p-` it scan all 65535 ports.